# Sustituir caracteres en columna durante SELECT SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una columna en mi base de datos que es algo así:

```
 -----------------
|     nombre      |
 -----------------
|   225/65/17  etc|
|  225/55C R17 etc|
|   xxx225/65 r16 |
|   235/65  17 etc|
|   etc 215/65 R17|
 -------------
```

Y necesito hacer un `select` buscando por nombre en el que el parámetro de búsqueda es por ejempplo `2256517`, es decir, necesito substituir las `/` por un "nada" `''`

EDITO:

Me he dado cuenta de que no todo está separado por una barra `/`, en algunos hay un espacio con una `R` en otros el el segundo "campo" acaba en una letra, espacio + otra letra...

Comment: Echa un vistazo a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37269038/579895)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar replace [Replace](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql)

```
 select * from Tabla 
  where replace(Campo,'/','') = '2256517'
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar la función de caracter [REPLACE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_replace.asp)

En caso de querer filtrar la busqueda deberias incluirlo en el WHERE de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT columna
FROM nombre_tabla
WHERE REPLACE(nombre,'/','')='2256517';
```

En caso de querer filtrar la salida deberías incluir la función en el SELECT:

```
SELECT REPLACE(columna,'/','') "Columna"
FROM nombre_tabla;
```

En caso de que contengan otros carácteres deberias de o cambiar la consulta y por lo tanto el replace o en caso que todos empiecen por 2 que es la sensación que me ha dado puedes utilizar RTRIM y LTRIM para eliminar los carácteres por la izquierda y la derech aque no te interesen. En tu caso sería algo así:

```
SELECT columna
FROM nombre_tabla
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(nombre,'/',''), 'r Rx'), 'r Rx')='2256517';
```

Esto eliminaría los caracteres a la izquierda y derecha que hay entre comillas cada uno por separado, ya solo haría falta jugar con el REPLACE, RTRIM y LTRIM hasta dar con la combinación dependiendo en las tuplas a obtener.